# cpuset does not work correctly for systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, cpuset

I am running kubelet service with systemd and trying to pin all kubelet processes to a single CPU core.

Edited `/sys/fs/cgroup/kube.slice/cpuset.cpus` and put 7. the `taskset` command shows the cofig is correct:

```
$ sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/kube.slice/cpuset.cpus.effective 
7
$ pidof kubelet 
2255
$ taskset -cp 2255
pid 2255's current affinity list: 7
```

But the process is still using other cores as well

```
$ ps -T -p 2255 -o pid,spid,psr
    PID    SPID PSR
   2255    2255   8
   2255    2256   7
   2255    2257   7
   2255    2258   8
   2255    2259   7
   2255    2260   5
   2255    2261   2
   2255    2262   1
   2255    2263   1
   2255    2264   8
...
```

I also checked `/sys/kernel/debug/sched/debug` and kublet processes are in fact running on other cores. `sudo service kubelet restart` didn't help either.

Am i doing something wrong or it is because systemd runs kublet?

```
$ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```